# Probability that none of the companies recieved my resume

Tags: probability

Imagine that 14 companies are hiring new employees.  I saw 6 of them and i sent my resume to them.
If 3 of these 6 companies are not in capital of the country, What is the probability that none of the companies placed in cities other than the capital, recieved my resume ?

Note :  My problem is that for me, it's not clear that  the use of the first sentence ( 14 companies are hiring ) is . The answer is $0.15$ but i don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you sent the resumes off to companies entirely at random (without looking where they were based, in particular) then:

There are $\binom {14}{6}$  ways in which you might have sent them off.  There are $\binom {11}{6}$ ways to send them only to the capital city firms.  Your answer is just the ratio:  $$\frac {\binom {11}{6}}{\binom {14}{6}}\sim 0.153846154$$

Comment: Can you please explain the part that we choose 6 from 11 more? I mean how do you know that the remaining 11 companies are surely from the capital city?

Comment: It's possible I misread the question.  I took the condition to read that "$3$ of the $14$ firms are in non-capital cities".  On re-reading, that's not what you say.  But still I suspect that I answered the intended question...no?

Comment: ِThe value ( 0.15 ) is correct ... but i can't understand the way you used :)

Comment: I am assuming that the intended question was "assume that you randomly send $6$ resumes to $14$ firms and that $3$ of those firms are non-capital and $11$ of them are capital firms, what is the probability that all of your resumes when to capital firms."  I understand that this isn't the way the question reads, but the way the question reads does not make sense.

Comment: To stress:  if the phrase "$3$ of these $6$ companies are not in the capital" means "exactly (or at least) three of the resumes you sent went outside the capital", then the answer to the question is plainly $0$ as we know for sure that some resumes went outside the capital.  I don't believe this is what was intended.

Comment: it seems that the book that i picked the question from, meaned something like what u said :) i'm satisfied :) thank you :)